# How can i listen in real-time for changes on my MongoDB?

Tags: python, mongodb

I have a DB where i am sending some data. At the same time i'm running a Python script and i would like this script to send on my console the last entry to the MongoDB database as soon as it's added.

I've been looking for a solution to this for days without finding anything.

I made some research and found about:
a) tailable cursor, but the only problem is that my database is not capped, and since i will be putting data every 5 seconds i'm afraid that a capped database would not be enough for my needs since when the max size it's reached it will start overwriting the oldest records b) change_streams, but my db is not a replica set, i'm fairly new to this so i still have to learn about more advanced topics like RS.

Any advice?

This is what i got so far:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import pymongo
import time
import random
from pprint import pprint

#Step 1: Connect to MongoDB - Note: Change connection string as needed
client = MongoClient(port=27017)


db = client.one

mycol = client["coll"]


highest_previous_primary_key = 1

while True:
    cursor = db.mycol.find()
    for document in cursor:

        # get the current primary key, and if it's greater than the previous one
        # we print the results and increment the variable to that value
        current_primary_key = document['num']
        if current_primary_key > highest_previous_primary_key:
            print(document['num'])
            highest_previous_primary_key = current_primary_key
```

But the problem with this it's that it will stop printing after the 4th record, plus i don't know if it's the best solution for when my db will have a lot of data.

Any advice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> b) change_streams, but my db is not a replica set, i'm fairly new to this so i still have to learn about more advanced topics like RS

[Replica sets](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/replication/) provide redundancy and high availability, and are the basis for all production MongoDB deployments. Having said that, for testing and/or deployment you can deploy a replica set with only a single member. For local testing example:

```
mongod --dbpath /path/data/test --replSet test
```

Once the local test server started, connect with [mongo](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/#bin.mongo) shell to perform [rs.initiate()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/rs.initiate/#rs.initiate):

```
mongo
> rs.initiate()
```

See related [Deploy a replica set for testing and deployment](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set-for-testing/)

```
try:
    # Only catch insert operations
    with client.watch([{'$match': {'operationType': 'insert'}}]) as stream:
        for insert_change in stream:
            print(insert_change)
except pymongo.errors.PyMongoError:
    # The ChangeStream encountered an unrecoverable error or the
    # resume attempt failed to recreate the cursor.
    logging.error('...')
```

See also [pymongo.mongo_client.MongoClient.watch()](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html#pymongo.mongo_client.MongoClient.watch)

Comment: Thank you! I'm looking more into replica sets.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit late but you can do so without replica set too by using following:

```
highest_previous_primary_key = 0

while True:
    cursor = collection.find()
    for document in cursor:

        # get the current primary key, and if it's greater than the previous one
        # we print the results and increment the variable to that value
        current_primary_key = collection.count()
        if current_primary_key > highest_previous_primary_key:
            curs = collection.find()
            curs[highest_previous_primary_key:]
            for i in curs:
                print(i)
            highest_previous_primary_key = current_primary_key
```